# Find specific element in jQuery's .each function and do something with it

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my markup:

```
<ul class="tab1">
<li><a href="http://site.com/some.html?param=1"></li>
<li><a href="http://site.com/some.html?param=2"></li>
<li><a href="http://site.com/some.html?param=3"></li>
...
</ul>
```

I'm trying to compare if the current window.location matches any of the list anchors, and if true, then I'd like to do something like addClass('active').

My code for checking the current location of the browser and getting the href parameters from the list elements:

```
// get current url parameter
var getBrowserUrl = document.URL.split('?')[1];

// get parameters of all the <li> anchors
jQuery('.tab1 a').each(function(){
    var getElementUrl = jQuery(this).attr('href').split('?')[1];
    if (getBrowserUrl == getElementUrl ) {
        jQuery(this).addClass('active');
    }
});
```

The jQuery(this) bit obviously isn't working, since 'this' will refer to all of the list elements.

How can i specify the matching list element?

Comment: No, `this` will refer to each matching element in turn.  What you have should work.  You might want to return false (breaking the iteration) once you've found a match.

Comment: Inside the .each() function, `this` is each matched element in turn; in your code, the three <a> elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested your code and made a few modifications try the following:

```
 <ul class="tab1">
     <li><a href="http://site.com/some.html?param=1"/></li>
     <li><a href="http://site.com/some.html?param=2"/></li>
     <li><a href="http://site.com/some.html?param=3" /></li>
</ul>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
         $(function () {
             // get current url parameter
             var getBrowserUrl = document.URL.split('?')[1];
             // get parameters of all the <li> anchors
             $('.tab1 a').each(function () {
                 var getElementUrl = $(this).attr('href').split('?')[1];
                 if (getBrowserUrl == getElementUrl) {
                     $(this).addClass('active');
                 }
             });
         });
     </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want better control of the items you are iterating through, add this to your `.each` function:

```
.each(function(index, value) { ... }
```

That way, value is the element you are looking to find.

Comment: Thanks shanabus. I actually figured it out now, a few minutes after posting this question.

`jQuery('.tab a').each(function(){
var getElementUrl = jQuery(this).attr('href').split('?')[1];
if (getBrowserUrl == getElementUrl) {
jQuery(this).css('backgroundColor', 'red');
}
});`